Error deploying Google Cloud Function: Python builder image not found
I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud Function that's triggered by a specific Pub/Sub topic. While the function and Pub/Sub topic linkage is configured correctly, I'm getting an error during the build process. The function fails to build because it cannot find the Python builder image.
Error:
[12:56:18 PM] - Preparing function sources ...
[12:56:19 PM] - Building function sources ...
[12:56:19 PM] - Building 1st gen event-driven function might take longer than usual
[12:56:19 PM] - Error: Command failed: cd /gcf-working-dir/function-sources && pack build gcf-ui-function --builder gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder --pull-policy if-not-present --env GOOGLE_FUNCTION_TARGET=hello_pubsub --env GOOGLE_FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE=event --env GOOGLE_DEVMODE=1 --env GOOGLE_RUNTIME_VERSION=3.10

ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:latest': image 'gcr.io/gae-runtimes/buildpacks/google-gae-22/python/builder:latest' does not exist on the daemon: not found


This behavior is a known issue on the Google Cloud Run functions' side, especially, if you are using the TEST FUNCTION feature. This prevents the function from being tested or deployed – even if triggered by Pub/Sub.
Suggested workaround is to test the function locally via functions framework or functions emulator (Preview).
If the issue persists, you can upvote/comment in this public issue tracker to monitor updates directly from the engineering team or keep an eye on the release notes. Note that there’s no specific timeline when the fix will be available.
